# Redis replication order

Tags: redis

In a master-slave scenario, Redis replication is made in an asynchronous way. But is it guaranteed that the commands are replicated in order? If I have these commands:

```
SET key1 111
SET key2 222
SET key3 333
```

If the slave node has "key2", then I can say for sure that it'll also have "key1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, commands are replicated in order. Anything else wouldn't actually be replication.

As described in [the documentation](https://redis.io/topics/replication#how-redis-replication-works), both the master and the replica keep track of an `offset` indicating where they are in the stream of commands. That allows the replica to know if it receives a command out of order and not process it prematurely.